# integrate ext js v4.2.1 with zend framework v1.11

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, extjs

I'm trying to create an application using zend framework and ext js for the client side. 
So far i've created a zend app using Zend_Tool. 
My questions are:

1. Where to put the Ext Js libraries.
2. Where to import them to use in the whole app i'm building.

well for some reson i can't comment on my post....
thanks doydoy let me be more specific

the project is running, ext libraries are in public/js, now i want to layout my app with extjs, i want to know how to communicate zend with ext js

Answer (score 0):

1. To use a JS library, it must be put into the `public` directory (or a subdirectory of the `public`) like `public/js/your_library.js`
2. To import the library in your app, you can do in a Controller:
   -> To put it in the head:

   ```
   $this->view->headScript()->prependFile($this->view->baseUrl().'/js/your_library.js');
   ```

   -> To put it in bottom of the body:

   ```
   $this->view->InlineScript()->prependFile($this->view->baseUrl().'/js/your_library.js');
   ```
3. To call it in the layout

   -> In the head:

   ```
       <head>
           <?php echo $this->headScript();?>
       </head>
   ```

   -> In the bottom of the boddy

   ```
   <body>
       ...
       <?php echo $this->InlineScript(); ?>
   </body>
   ```
4. To add your own script

   ```
   $this->view->InlineScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl() . '/js/your_file.js');
   ```

`prependFile()` method adds the top of the list, and `appendFile()` method adds at the end of the list.

It is better to use `prependFile` for libraries like jQuery and `appendFile` for scripts that need these libraries